# Not able to Display without storing it in DB

Tags: php, html, image

I am not sure whether I am displaying the image in the right way or not. I am not able to display the image in the given field and the images are not stored in DB ...it's a gender based avatar choosing script (I hope so).

```
if (isset($_GET['gender']) == 'm') {
    echo ' <img id="avat" src="imgs/avatar-boy-1.png" alt="">';
} elseif (isset($_GET['gender']) == 'f') {
    echo ' <img id="avat" src="imgs/avatar-girl-1.png" alt="">';
}
```

Comment: All of your conditional statements are false positives. You need to break them into separate statements.

Comment: If you remove `isset(` does it work? i.e. `if($_GET['gender']=='m')`

Comment: if ($_GET['gender'] = 'm') {
    echo ' <img id="avat" src="imgs/avatar-boy-1.png" alt="">';
} elseif($_GET['gender'] = 'f') {
    echo ' <img id="avat" src="imgs/avatar-girl-1.png" alt="">';
}   doesnt work for the 'f'...only the first statement runs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Funk Forty Niner and Dharman pointed this out in the comments, but `isset($_GET['gender'])=='m'` doesn't make sense.

`isset($_GET['gender'])` returns a boolean, true or false, telling you whether `$_GET['gender']` is set. You can't meaningfully compare that boolean to `'m'`.

You probably want something like `isset($_GET['gender']) && $_GET['gender'] == 'm'`.
Or just move the `isset($_GET['gender'])` into its own if statement, since you are checking it both times.

Comment: thanks for responding ...

                            if(  $_GET['gender']='m'){

                                echo '<img id="avat" src="imgs/boy.png" >';
                           
                            }elseif(  $_GET['gender']='f'){
    
                                echo ' <img id="avat" src="imgs/girl.png" > ';
                            
                            }

i understood that my previous "if" statement was wrong but now get only above the second statement is not even taken into consideration by my code

ps: i am literally new to PHP

Comment: It needs to be `$_GET['gender'] == 'm'` (two equal signs, which checks for equality). In both if blocks, you need two equal signs.

When you just use one equals sign, you are setting `$_GET['gender']` to the value `'m'`.